# ng-switch to place elements

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-switch

Any better way to write this? I just dont want to repeat the inner content of the list twice.

```
 <div ng-switch on="list.type">
   <ul ng-switch-when="unorder">
    <li ng-repeat="item in items">
            {{ item.text }}
    </li>
   </ul ng-switch-when="unorder">
    <ol ng-switch-when="order">
        <li ng-repeat="item in items">
            {{ item.text }}
        </li>
    </ol ng-switch-when="order">
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is more elegant way by using css instead of using custom-directive for something quite simple

**Html**

```
<ol ng-class="{'no-style' : list.type === 'unorder'}">
    <li ng-repeat="item in items">
        {{ item.text }}
    </li>
</ol>
```

**CSS**

```
ol.no-style {
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

Live example you can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Lz2575vc/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
  <list content="list.type">
    <li ng-repeat="item in items">
      {{ item.text }}
    </li>
  </list>
</div>
```

With a data binding you can change the list directive template to 
`<ul ng-transclude>`or `<ol ng-transclude>`